# ASP.NET- What is the type of the args.Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

A custom validator has properties called ClientValidationFunction and ControlToValidate. The function is like this:

```
function MyValidationFunction(source,args) {
   if(args.Value==......)
}
```

I know that here '*source*' is the ControlToValidate. But I can't understand what the type of the args.Value is. What does it take as a Value. When the controltovalidate is a textbox I know it's the text of that textbox but what is it if the control is a user control. So my question is what is the Value to validate and can we change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, for client-side validation, the `Value` property of the rendered HTML control is used, which makes sense, for example, for `TextBox` controls, which are rendered as a simple `<input type="text">` (and whose [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485) property contains the content of the text box). If a (custom) control consists of multiple HTML controls, client-side validation is not feasible, according to the following Knowledge Base article:

- [How to extend a Web Form control to work with the validation controls by using Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310082):

> **NOTE:** This article demonstrates how to extend the Calendar control for server-side validation only. For client-side validation to occur, the validation controls hook up to the corresponding HTML control's **Value** property. Because many HTML controls are used to build the Calendar control, no single HTML control contains the selected value for the Calendar control. Thus, client-side validation is not appropriate for the Calendar control.

By the way, for *server-side validation*, you can use the [`ValidationProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.validationpropertyattribute.aspx) attribute to specify which property is used for validation.

---

**EDIT**: According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383570/validate-web-user-control), if you output an `<input type="hidden">` as the first control of your user control, this will be used for client-side validation. This might be a useful workaround, if you are comfortable with storing your actual control value in there.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)

> Two parameters are passed into your client function, corresponding to
>   the parameters that are passed to the server function. The first is
>   the client validator element, and the second is the equivalent of the
>   arguments on the server. It has two properties, the Value, which
>   contains the input to be validated and IsValid, which you can update
>   to indicate validity.

```
function CheckEven(source, args) {
    var val = parseInt(args.Value, 10);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = ((val % 2) == 0);
    }
}
```

You can not change value, it is readonly. check [erverValidateEventArgs.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs.value.aspx) 
and [Using the CustomValidator Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx)